# Can't use *ngFor with *ngIf

Tags: angular, typescript

Use Angular 2

When i do it:

```
<ul>
    <template *ngFor="let flag of [1,2,3,4]">
        <li  *ngIf="flag == 1">
            some data
        </li>
    </template>
</ul>
```

I get it

```
<ul>
    <!--template bindings={
      "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "1,2,3,4"
    }-->
    <!--template bindings={}-->
    <!--template bindings={}-->
    <!--template bindings={}-->
    <!--template bindings={}-->
</ul>
```

And it display nothing.
I need to display `<li>` in *ngFor only when `item.flagsExplain[flag]` is set

Comment: Please give a [mcve] that includes the inputs to this.

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: But where are the *inputs*? What is `item`? `service`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for syntactic sugar:

```
<ul>
    <ng-container*ngFor="let flag of service.flagsCount()">
        <li  *ngIf="item.flagsExplain[flag]">
            {{ service.flagLabel(flag) }}
            <b *ngIf="item.flagsExplain[flag] != 1">
                : {{ item.flagsExplain[flag] }}
            </b>
        </li>
    </ng-container>
</ul>
```

if you wanna using `template` tag, you need using this form:

```
<template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="items" let-i="index" [ngForTrackBy]="trackByFn">
  <li>...</li>
</template>
```

and in Angular 4:

```
<ng-template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="items" let-i="index" [ngForTrackBy]="trackByFn">
  <li>...</li>
</ng-template>
```

so your code will look like this:

```
<ul>
    <template ngFor let-flag [ngForOf]="service.flagsCount()">
        <li  *ngIf="item.flagsExplain[flag]">
            some data
        </li>
    </template>
</ul>
```

p/s: replace `template` tag with `ng-template` in Angular 4.

document here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgForOf-directive.html

Comment: Thanks, it work!

Comment: please take a look my updated answer.